# I cannot create newAccount on Geth JavaScript

Tags: go-ethereum

[image]

I cannot create newAccount
Please give me solution.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04
geth 1.12.0-stable-e501b3b0

Comment: Personal_* namespace has been deprecated for a while. Now clef should be used to manage accounts https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/account-management.